# Session flash not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel 5.2 I am trying to using session flash for display Alert

Here are the code for the session flash

**DepartmentContoller.php**

```
public function add(Request $request ){

        if($request->isMethod('post'))
        {
            $department = new Department;

            /*$department->department_name = $request->department_name;
            $department->status = $request->status;
            $department->save();*/

            $department->create($request->all());
            $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'User was successful added!');
            return redirect('admin/departments');
        }

        return view('admin.department.add');
    }
```

Here is the view file where I want to display session flash value

```
@foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
  {{Session::has('alert-' . $msg)}}
  @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))
      <div class="alert alert-{{$msg}} alert-dismissible">
        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
        <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Alert!</h4>
        {{session('alert-'. $msg)}}
      </div>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

And here is my route deatail

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
//Login Routes...
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::get('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('/admin/logout','AdminAuth\AuthController@logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
Route::post('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@register');    

Route::group(['as' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['admin', 'web'], 'prefix'=>'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', array('uses'=>'AdminController@index'));
    Route::get('/departments', array('as' => 'departments', 'uses'=>'DepartmentController@index'));
    Route::get('/department/add', array('as' => 'add', 'uses'=>'DepartmentController@add'));
    Route::post('/department/add', array('as' => 'add', 'uses'=>'DepartmentController@add'));
});
```

});

I want to show success alert in view, but I didn't get the session value on my view page. Please suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: Since `flash`is used only for the next request, are you sure there aren't more redirections after `admin/departments`? However, I guess you should use `{{ session('alert-' . $msg) }}` instead of `{{ session('message') }}`

Comment: Yes, there are no other redirection are there, and also I have changed with `{{ session('alert-' . $msg) }}`. But no luck, It's not go inside the `if(session::has('alert-' . $msg))`

Comment: Try to retrieve the session data in the controller and then pass them to the view from `DepartmentController@index`

Comment: I have checked session with the DepartmentController@index, I didn't found the `alert-success` in this action, but when I show session array after the `assign session()->flash()` It is showing the `alert-success`.

Comment: Use session helper: session()->flash('message', 'Your message');

Answer (score 0):

## make sure all routes uses web middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
// routes here
Route::get('/departments', array('as' => 'departments',    'uses'=>'DepartmentController@index'));
});
```

Comment: My route is using web middleware

Comment: Do u get an error -->RuntimeException with the message 'Session store not set on request'.

Comment: session()->flash('alert-success', 'User was successful added!'); 
    return redirect()->to('admin/departments');